# Select Query in T Sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Need one help in formulating select query.

I have a table with 50 columns in it, now i want to retrieve not all the columns from this table.

i.e, say i have col like: a,b,c,d & i want a select query without column c,d. I know using simply `select a, b from table` will serve the purpose, but think when there are 50 columns and you want to retrieve only 40 from them.

Is there any specific T-SQL in sql server syntax available that will full fill the requirement.

Comment: Do you want to select the "first 40 columns out of a possible 50"?

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't say "select all columns except c,d" but if you use Object Explorer, expand the tables or views node, expand your table or view, and drag the "Columns" folder onto the query window. Now you can delete the 10 columns from the list that you don't want, which should be easier than typing out the other 40.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it *is* possible to select all the columns except certain ones you specify.  It just isn't something you should normally do.

For instance:

```
DECLARE @columns VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @columns = COALESCE(@columns+',' ,'') + name
FROM MyDatabase.sys.columns
WHERE object_id = (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM MyDatabase.sys.tables
    WHERE name='MyTable'
)
    AND name NOT IN ('MyColumn1','MyColumn2')
PRINT @columns

EXEC('SELECT '+@columns+' FROM MyTable')
```

Generally, it's better to follow the examples given in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do like `Select * except c,d from table`. You have to write each column name manually. If you don't want to write each column name manually you can use `Script Table As` by right clicking on *table* or *view* in Object Explorer like this:

> [image]

Then you will get whole `SELECT` query in *New Query Editor Window* then remove unwanted column like this:

> [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using it regularly Creating view will help.
although you have to do it once.

Answer (score 0):

Click **New Query** - type in "select * from table". Highlight text with cursor. Right click highlight, select **Design Query in Editor**, clear the check marks for the columns you don't want. Click **OK**. I find that writing code in the Editor can be really fast once you get used to it. Much faster than waiting for Intellisense try to figure out what you are trying to do.

When you write queries this way, it really helps to have a formatting tool like [Poor Man's T-SQL Formatter](http://www.architectshack.com/PoorMansTSqlFormatter.ashx) because the code generated by the Editor is usually unreadable.